# Pass data between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I want to transfer the user ID from the main Activity to a fragment.

So in the main activity, I do:

```
 Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
 final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("id_User", id);
 Log.i("BUNDLE", bundle.toString());
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in the log I can see

```
BUNDLE : Bundle[{id_User=1}]
```

In the fragment, I test it in `onCreate`

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
if (arguments != null)
{
Log.i("BUNDLE != null","NO NULL");
} else {
Log.i("BUNDLE == null","NULL");
}
```

And I have

```
BUNDLE == null: NULL
```

So the transfer is successful, but how can I receive the data in fragment, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
 Bundle args = getArguments();
 if (args  != null && args.containsKey("id_User"))
     String userId = args.getString("id_User");
```

Comment: what should i do if i have to retrieve data in user defined method not in oncreate method.

Comment: @AndroidLearner It would be better if you posted a separate question with a proper description of your problem. Provide your code and me or someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: @AndroidLearner Did you solved your problem? i have such a problem :/

Comment: @Szymon : Can we pass data between two fragments without an activity? I have parent fragment in which there are two child fragments and i need to pass data between two child fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
String User = getArguments().getString("id_User", "Default Value");
```

The default value you supply will be returned if the key you request does not exist.