# how to retain data between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using 3 Fragments A,B,C with Tabhost Fragment Activity

Frag A,B,C each contains some fields belongs to one class only .That is Say Employee class

A contains EMpnm,EmpAge,EmpNo
B contains EMpJoinDt,EmpSal
C contains EmpHobby,EmpPersonalDtls

navigation is A->B->C using next button

Employee class is public .data frm each fragment set to Employee class using getter/Setter
Each fragment will have Employee emp= new Employee() object

so every time data get wipe out on next button click from Frag A to B so data dnt get hold by emp object how to retain data from fragment 1 to 2 to 3 so that at the end on submit whole Class employee get submitted with values to DB

**is shared preferences best solution for it?** 
**Is It good solution for my Case?  using bundle**

[Link][Pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036548/pass-data-between-fragments)
Note:the same class for each fragment

Comment: Why don't your use some BaseFragmentActivity class to hold the whole employee details (that would be retained while swiping or tab click on other tabs) would be retained. Later you can use this to save them to the database.

Comment: ok let me try ..thnks for reply

Comment: Yes.... Shared Preference is very good to store data. Another option is to handle with also Sqlite database.

Comment: do you want to edit the object between the fragments?

Comment: aditi do u know about singleton class

Comment: @Bartosz Filipowicz no ...dnt want to edit just want to hold data and store on submit

Comment: You can put all these variables in static class which will be defined in activity.

Comment: Is It good solution for my Case? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036548/pass-data-between-fragments) using bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharedPreferences is definitely not a good solution. It is designed to be a key/value data store for basic data types. Also it should be rather used for application wide preferences rather than cache for business data.

Preferably you should store the common object in the Activity that hosts all your fragments, and save/restore it via `onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState` mechanics.

Alternatively you can create a UI-less fragment to hold the shared data. You would add this fragment in your activity before initializing other fragments.

Then you can access such fragment via `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG)`. In this case you will need to save your objects instance state within fragment to prevent state loss on configuration changes.

Simple concept of Activity as the data holder:

```
public interface EmployeeDataHolder {
    EmployeeData getEmployeeData();
}

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements EmployeeDataHolder {
  private EmployeeData mEmployeeData;

  @Override
  public EmployeeData getEmployeeData() {
    return mEmployeeData;
  }
}

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment{

  EmployeeDataHolder mEmployeeDataHolder;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof EmployeeDataHolder) {
      mEmployeeDataHolder = (EmployeeDataHolder) activity;
    } else 
      throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement EmployeeDataHolder interface");
  }

  private void yourEmployeeDataProcessingMethod(){
    EmployeeData employeeData = mEmployeeDataHolder.getEmployeeData();
    // process data, populate views etc.
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mEmployeeDataHolder = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @AditiK I've edited the answer to give you a sample of activity as the data holder

Comment: Is It good solution for my Case? using bundle

[Link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036548/pass-data-between-fragments

Comment: Yes, it will work. The difference is that it won't be the same Employee object in all the fragments, but rather a separate copy in each of them. Another downside of using fragment arguments is that once you set it, you cannot modify it. But in the end this should work in your case.

Comment: Should the reference to the activity not be a [WeakReference<Activity>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences is definitely an option.

Even simpler, you could make the fields of Employee holder class static. This way the values set to the fields will remain as your incrementally input data through the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your fragments navigation through this `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, true);`
Throught this data fields will be retained automatically.

If you want to access all fragment data and fields you can try this.

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: question is  not for data retain in view ..its for storing to database using POJO.read Bartosz Filipowicz answer to this

Comment: @AditiK i have edit by answer you can see it if this help you

Comment: how to get data for Spinner ?