# Preserve previous data of a different layout on orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-inflate, onconfigurationchanged

I have a fragment in an activity containing two layouts to show each for different orientations.

For portrait orientation, **firstLayout**.

For landscape orientation, **secondLayout**.

Both the layouts are shown in a same container.

So I have something like -

```
 if ((getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                    && getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) 
    {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstLayout, container, false);
            //data

            return view;
    }
    else
    {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondLayout, container, false);
            return view;
    }
```

So when the user rotates the device (portrait to landscape), layout `secondLayout` is called.
When the user again rotates the device while in a layout `secondLayout`, the other layout of the fragment i.e. layout `firstLayout` is called back in.

**The problem is** -

The layout `firstLayout` is taking so much time to load back as if application hanged for some time as it is doing so much of initialization stuff in `onCreate()`.

Having so, I wanted that layout `firstLayout` should be called without a call to `onCreate()` in a fragment.

So I  just did-

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and then overridden the method `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` by just inflating my layout `firstLayout`. But by doing this I lost my previous data.

I also heard about `setRetainState(true)` to use to retain the previous state but I am not sure how to use it to get the previous data on orientation change.

What is the best way to show the layout `firstLayout` on orientation change in as faster way as it is when it appears when user clicks the back button (for example)?

Answer (score 0):

setRetainState(true) don't work with 2 fragments, so you have to pass data betwee those 2 fragments:

google's code:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

some examples on stackoverflow:
[Pass data between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036548/pass-data-between-fragments)
[Data Sharing between Fragments and Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445594/data-sharing-between-fragments-and-activity-in-android)

or simply storing the data in class variables

if the user has to input data, don't forget to override on onCreateView and attach the data on onAttach

more info here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html